# Cannot query foreign key field in GraphQL

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm using graphene-django framework for GraphQL.
All fields I can retrieve except foreign key

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import UserProfile

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
# schema.py

class VideoType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
```

My query is like this

```
query {
  home_videos {
    title
    description
    author
  }
}
```

Following is error message in GraphQLView.

> Cannot query field author on type VideoType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added UserType and changed model foreignKey type

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

```
author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I display `ForeignKey` fields using the standard `ObjectType` to create custom fields.

```
# Specify fields format
class CustomObject(graphene.ObjectType):
    returns = graphene.Float()
    dt = graphene.DateTime()
    strategy = graphene.String()
    exid = graphene.String()
    market = graphene.String()


# Build the query
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    target = graphene.Field(CustomObject, strategy_name=graphene.String(required=True))
    targets = graphene.List(CustomObject,
                            strategy_name=graphene.String(required=True),
                            length=graphene.Int(required=True))

    def resolve_target(self, info, strategy_name):
        obj = Target.objects.filter(strategy__name=strategy_name).latest('dt')

        # Fill fields value
        return CustomObject(
            returns=obj.returns,
            dt=obj.dt,
            strategy=obj.strategy.name,  # <- ForeignKey fields
            exid=obj.exchange.exid,  # <- ForeignKey fields
            market=obj.market.symbol  # <- ForeignKey fields
        )
```